# How to make a timer command that can display hours, minutes and seconds? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a timer command that can only ask and display seconds, but I want command that will ask and display minutes and hours too and I have no idea how I can do it.

```
@client.command()
async def timer(ctx, seconds):
    try:
       text = (seconds)
       in_seconds = {'h': 60 * 60, 'm': 60, 's': 1}
       seconds = sum(int(num) * in_seconds[weight if weight else 's'] for num, weight in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)?', text))
       if seconds > 86400:
            await ctx.send("I'm not going to set a timer for you for more than a day!")
            raise BaseException
       if seconds < 0:
            await ctx.send("You know I can't travel to the past, right?")
            raise BaseException
       message = await ctx.send(f"Timer: {seconds}")
       while True:
            seconds -= 1
            if seconds < 0:
                await message.edit(content=f"{ctx.author.mention}, your countdown has ended!")
                break
            await message.edit(content=f"Timer: {seconds}")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.75)
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send('Must be a number!')
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, I googled a little and was able to make the following command

```
@client.command()
async def timer(ctx, seconds):
    try:
       text = (seconds)
       in_seconds = {'h': 60 * 60, 'm': 60, 's': 1}
       seconds = sum(int(num) * in_seconds[weight if weight else 's'] for num, weight in re.findall(r'(\d+)\s?(m|s|h)?', text))
       emb1 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"Timer: {seconds//3600} hours {seconds%3600//60} minutes {seconds%60} seconds")
       emb2 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"Timer: {seconds%3600//60} minutes {seconds%60} seconds")
       emb3 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"Timer: {seconds%60} seconds")
       emb4 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"{ctx.author.mention}, your countdown has ended!")       
       if seconds > 86400:
            await ctx.send("I'm not going to set a timer for you for more than a day!")
            raise BaseException
       if seconds < 1:
            await ctx.send("You know I can't travel to the past, right?")
            raise BaseException
       if seconds >= 3600:
            message = await ctx.send(embed = emb1)
       elif seconds >= 60:
            message = await ctx.send(embed = emb2)
       elif seconds < 60:
            message = await ctx.send(embed = emb3)
       while True:
            seconds -= 1
       emb1 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"Timer: {seconds//3600} hours {seconds%3600//60} minutes {seconds%60} seconds")
       emb2 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"Timer: {seconds%3600//60} minutes {seconds%60} seconds")
       emb3 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"Timer: {seconds%60} seconds")
       emb4 = discord.Embed(title="Timer", colour=0xA30000, description= f"{ctx.author.mention}, your countdown has ended!") 
            if seconds >= 3600:
                await message.edit(embed = emb1)
            elif seconds >= 60:
                await message.edit(embed = emb2)
            elif seconds < 60:
                await message.edit(embed = emb3)
            if seconds < 0:
                await message.edit(embed = emb4)
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.25)
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send('Must be a number!')
```